# Pass a variable to template in Middleman 2

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have a Middleman project and I need to emulate a logged-in user.

Simple enough - would be fine to set some global variable like @user = 1 in config.rb, code everything for the logged-in user, then set the variable to 0 and code everything for the logged-out user putting if's everywhere

I'm not a Ruby coder so I don't understand where to hook in.
So: how can I set a global app variable in a middleman's config.rb?

Comment: [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) is a static site generator. What do you mean by loggining in?

Comment: I wrote: ***emulate a logged-in user***. Then I explained it in the next sentence. I need to defined a variable in config.rb, then make is visible to the template.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set variable on specific paths using the `page` helper:

```
page "/my-page.html", :locals => { :is_logged_in => true }
```

If you wanted to use a single template, which include an `if` statement to handle content changes based on `is_logged_in`, you would use a page proxy:

```
page "/my-page-logged-in.html", :proxy => "/my-page.html", :locals => { :is_logged_in => true }
page "/my-page-logged-out.html", :proxy => "/my-page.html", :locals => { :is_logged_in => false }
```

For direct variables, use `set`:

```
set :is_logged_in, true
```

In template:

```
<%= is_logged_in %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the highlights. These go directly to config.rb, right? But actually what I need is a bit simpler - I want this var to be seen in all templates. Actually it is primarily needed for the layout: header and footer are different for logged in / out users, and I will have if's in both. I (and other coders) will then switch the variable in config.rb and view the site in 2 modes.

Comment: Doesn't work (currently) with Middleman 4 beta 2, as it seems.